# Flex with gap fill space in last row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I use flex with gap, the last row has some space at the end (I think equal in size to gap): https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnzj4ya/

Why doesn't the last row take up all the space like the first one? It does if I remove the gap, but I want the gap between items. My understanding is `align-items: stretch` (the default) should fill all the space.

Interestingly, I have this problem in JSFiddle and on my website, but not in the Stackoverflow code snippet:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="First name">
  <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="Last name">
  <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="Address">
  <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="Email">
  <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
```

Image of problem (there is a space after the "Phone" input):
[image]

Comment: can you please add image of the issue facing

Comment: Added image. Just realized I also don't get the problem in private browser, which made me think to try disabling the LastPass extension... and then the problem goes away! Of all the reasons not to use LastPass, huh...

Comment: Hah, yep, I'm using Lastpass too, getting the same issue. While I use `input` all the time, this is a first for me. Reason to dig a bit deeper... Found it already, it's Lastpass interfering because of the `placeholder` values. Changed them for testing and the issue disappeared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that **[Lastpass](https://www.lastpass.com)** password vault app uses the exact same `input placeholder` values to trigger placement of its *input auto-fill options icon*.

It's an SVG and it happens to be `max-width: 22px` and `max-height: 18px`

Inserting this in your CSS seems to solve the issue, it will disable the icon, but not the underlying *Lastpass* functionality:

```css
div[data-lastpass-icon-root] { display: none }
```

A rather sloppy development solution by *Lastpass*, as it should in no way have to interfere with the regular flow of a client HTML document.

For the interested, the injected HTML:

```html
<div data-lastpass-icon-root="true" style="position: relative !important; height: 0px !important; width: 0px !important; float: left !important;"></div>
```

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" data-lastpass-icon="true" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; height: 18px; max-height: 18px; width: 22px; max-width: 22px; top: -40px; left: -443.667px; z-index: auto; color: rgb(215, 64, 58);"><rect x="0.680176" y="0.763062" width="22.6392" height="22.4737" rx="4" fill="currentColor"></rect><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M19.7935 7.9516C19.7935 7.64414 20.0427 7.3949 20.3502 7.3949C20.6576 7.3949 20.9069 7.64414 20.9069 7.9516V16.0487C20.9069 16.3562 20.6576 16.6054 20.3502 16.6054C20.0427 16.6054 19.7935 16.3562 19.7935 16.0487V7.9516Z" fill="white"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.76288 13.6577C5.68525 13.6577 6.43298 12.9154 6.43298 11.9998C6.43298 11.0842 5.68525 10.3419 4.76288 10.3419C3.8405 10.3419 3.09277 11.0842 3.09277 11.9998C3.09277 12.9154 3.8405 13.6577 4.76288 13.6577Z" fill="white"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.3298 13.6577C11.2521 13.6577 11.9999 12.9154 11.9999 11.9998C11.9999 11.0842 11.2521 10.3419 10.3298 10.3419C9.4074 10.3419 8.65967 11.0842 8.65967 11.9998C8.65967 12.9154 9.4074 13.6577 10.3298 13.6577Z" fill="white"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.8964 13.6577C16.8188 13.6577 17.5665 12.9154 17.5665 11.9998C17.5665 11.0842 16.8188 10.3419 15.8964 10.3419C14.974 10.3419 14.2263 11.0842 14.2263 11.9998C14.2263 12.9154 14.974 13.6577 15.8964 13.6577Z" fill="white"></path></svg>
```